# Chrome performance profiler crashes on processing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to use the chrome performance profiler but it keeps crashing when processing the report.

Is there a way to get around this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable "Javascript samples", but the result is disappointing because it won't show you your code performance.

[image]